# Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for handling inputs

Tags: list, vector, nlp, translation, transformer-model

After running the below lines there is an error

```
source_vectorization = TextVectorization(
max_tokens=15000, output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=23,)
train_source_texts = [line[3] for line in multi_lingual_text]
source_vectorization.adapt(train_source_texts)
```

shows error:

> RuntimeError: Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for handling inputs. Found multiple adapters     [<class 'keras.engine.data_adapter.ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter'>, <class 'keras.engine.data_adapter.GenericArrayLikeDataAdapter'>] to handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.str_'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>